Collecting distinct field value from an object in Java stream
I am trying to collect distinct values of the one of the field in the object. I was hoping to use distinct() over stream however it can't be applied on field level. I have used Map to get the list mapped to object. Is there a way to get list of field only?
I have Employee object with ManagerId and I would like to collect distinct ManagerId list.
My Map Solution
Map<Long, Employee> employeeMap =employees.stream()
     .collect(Collectors.toMap(Employee::getManagerId, Function.identity(), (o, n) -> n);

I am looking to get List<Long> managerIds = .....

You can collect the IDs using the distinct() method on the stream:
List<Long> managerIds = employees.stream()
    .map(Employee::getManagerId)
    .distinct()
    .toList();

Here is a basic code snippet:
import java.util.List;
import java.util.function.Function;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Employee> employees = List.of(
            new Employee(1L, "Alice", 10L),
            new Employee(2L, "Bob", 20L),
            new Employee(3L, "Charlie", 10L),
            new Employee(4L, "David", 30L),
            new Employee(5L, "Eve", 20L)
        );

        List<Long> uniqueManagerIds = findUniqueManagerIds(employees);
        System.out.println("Unique Manager IDs: " + uniqueManagerIds); 
        // Output: [10, 20, 30]
    }

    public static List<Long> findUniqueManagerIds(List<Employee> employees) {
        return employees.stream()
            .map(Employee::getManagerId)
            .distinct()
            .toList();
    }
}

Assuming your Employee class looks similar:
public class Employee {
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private Long managerId;

    public Employee(Long id, String name, Long managerId) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.managerId = managerId;
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public Long getManagerId() {
        return managerId;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return String.format("Employee{id=%d, name='%s', managerId=%d}", id, name, managerId);
    }
}


To get a list of distinct ManagerId you have to stream the list of employees and collect it as a List<Long>
The method .toList(); is supported from Java 16.
If you want support for older Java versions use .collect(Collectors.toList());
List<Long> managerIds = employees.stream()
    .map(Employee::getManagerId)
    .distinct()
    .toList();


You repeated an answer that was posted an hour ago.  See Mr. Polywhirl's answer
